# Meaning of yield within fixture in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I read the documentation at [docs.pytest.org](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures)
I'm not sure about the meaning of the statement: `yield smtp_connection`

Can please someone explain what `yield` does, and if it's mandatory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not mandatory!!!
Yield execute test body, for example, you can set up your test with pre-condition and post condition. For this thing we can use conftest.py:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def set_up_pre_and_post_conditions():
    print("Pre condition")
    yield # this will be executed our test
    print("Post condition")
```

Our test, for example store in test.py:

```
def test(set_up_pre_and_post_conditions):
    print("Body of test")
```

So, let's launch it: pytest test.py -v -s
Output:

```
test.py::test Pre condition
Body of test
PASSEDPost condition
```

It's not full functionality of yield, just example, I hope it will be helpful.