# Pytest Multiple @pytest.mark.parametrize with one setup

Tags: pytest

First of all, my English is poor and I'm new here. I'm sorry if I do something wrong.

My question is if I have multiple parameters, but I only want call setup_method once for every test_function.

However, it call setup every parameters (test case). I don't know how to solve this problem.

Here is my code：

```
class Test_Class:

    def setup_method(self):    
        print("==========set up===========")


    @pytest.mark.parametrize('people', ['Mike','Alice','Bob'])
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('say', ['Hi','how is going on'])
    def test_function(self, people, say):
        print(people, say)
```

Here is the result

```
==========set up===========
Mike Hi

==========set up===========
Alice Hi

==========set up===========
Bob Hi

==========set up===========
Mike how is going on

==========set up===========
Alice how is going on

==========set up===========
Bob how is going on
```

But I want the result like this：

```
==========set up===========
Mike Hi

Alice Hi

Bob Hi

==========set up===========
Mike how is going on

Alice how is going on

Bob how is going on
```

The setup function is called with the next parameter.

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your approach is correct that is the root cause.
Usually, default parametrizing with list or key:value approach will be enough, try to deep investigate your aims. From my opinion you need to look at key:value approach, for example:

```
>>> a = ['Mike','Alice','Bob']
>>> b = ['Hi','how is going on']
>>> c = {x:a for x in b}
>>> c
{'Hi': ['Mike', 'Alice', 'Bob'], 'how is going on': ['Mike', 'Alice', 'Bob']}
```

approach -> Action: [list of names]

Also, you can prepare your data using pre-condition, for example in conftest.py, please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60430631/4361977

If my suggestions is not actual, so please provide real example and I will try to help you.